# Limit of a definite integral as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

On a test I had a problem that states:
*Find the limit:*
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}$$
*where $p>0$.*

So this is what I did. Since we know that $$\left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rvert\le\frac{1}{x}\implies\frac{-1}{x}\le\frac{\sin x}{x}\le\frac{1}{x}$$
I then integrated and took a limit of this so I could use squeeze theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{-1}{x}dx}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{1}{x}dx}$$
Let's start by solving the two limits on the outskirts of the inequality:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{-1}{x}dx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(- \ln x\right)\rvert_{n}^{n+p}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\ln(n+p)+\ln(n)\right)= \ln\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+p-p}{n+p}\right)=\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+p-p}{n+p}\right)=\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{p}{n+p}\right)^{\frac{n+p}{p}\cdot\frac{p}{n+p}}=\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{p}{n+p}dx}=0$$
Analogously I found that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{1}{x}}=0$$
That means:
$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}\le0$$
And by applying the squeeze theorem it turns out that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+p}{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}=0$$

This is the solution I got. Is it possible that isn't correct? Could there be something I overlooked? The idea to the solution seems very easy even though this was supposed to be the hardest problem on the test.

Comment: It would have been faster to just say $\left|\int_n^{n+p}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\right|\leq\int_n^{n+p}\frac{dx}{x}=\ln(n+p)-\ln(n)=\ln\left(1+\frac{p}{n}\right)$, which approaches $0$, but yea. (Also, the requirement $p>0$ is not strictly necessary, since things will make sense once $n$ is large enough).

Comment: You made the computation of the limit under $\ln$ too complicated. That limit is clearly $1$.

Comment: It looks fine. An alternative proof is to apply the Cauchy criterion for the convergence of $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$.

Comment: @Asigan haven't worked with that yet. Does it relate to Cauchy criterion for convergence of series? And how to apply it here where both bounds approach $+\infty$

Comment: @Gary yeah, I just realized that now, but anyways it's nice to make sure, cause $0$ just didn't seem like the right answer

Comment: @bb_823 Here is a more intuitive explanation, since you say $0$ did not seem like the right answer. Let $F(t) = \int_0^t \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$. Then, by Dirichlet, we know that $\lim_{t \to \infty} F(t)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$. Your question boils down to computing: $\lim_{t \to \infty} (F(t+p) - F(t))$ $= \lim_{t \to \infty} F(t+p) - \lim_{t \to \infty} F(t)$ $= \lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) - \lim_{t \to \infty} F(t)$ $ = 0$. You could also visualise this by considering the area the integral represents.

Comment: @legionwhale didn't know about that rule, that makes this problem almost trivial. Nice

Comment: $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ exists. Cauchy's criterion says that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $M>0$ s.t. $\forall x_1, x_2$ s.t. $x_2>x_1>M$ we have $|\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx|<\epsilon$. Now do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is correct, albeit a bit long. Alternatively you could notice that

$$\left\lvert\int_n^{n+p}\frac{\sin x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert\leq\int_n^{n+p}\left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rvert~\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_n^{n+p}\frac{1}{n}~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{p}{n}\to0$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You had a typo in last integrand it should be $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @bb_823 no, it is supposed to be $\frac{1}{n}$. I am bounding $\left\lvert\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rvert\leq\frac{1}{n}$ on $[n,n+p]$ using that $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ in decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ and that $\lvert\sin x\rvert\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The point is that it makes the integral even easier to compute as you don't really need any antidervatives or any knowledge of the logarithm. Otherwise it would've just been the same solution that peek-a-boo suggested in the comments.

Comment: Oh i see, my bad. If it was $1/x$ than that would bring us back to the same tedious thing I did with $\ln$

Comment: @bb_823 Yep exactly. This way we can completely circumvent that